# ID4014: A SecurityTokenHandler is not registered to read security token

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, wif, asp.net-web-api

I'm desperately trying to consume JWT token from ACS for authorization to my webapi. I got it so far that it redirects me to ACS site and I can Login. After the callback to my site I get:

> ID4014: A SecurityTokenHandler is not registered to read security
>   token ('BinarySecurityToken',
>   'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd').

I've read alot of Blogs about this and I made my own CustomJwtSecurityToken. But somehow it still doesn't work. I did everything according to this site: http://blog.codit.eu/post/2013/03/19/Using-ACS-and-WAAD-with-JWT-Tokens-for-Web-and-Store-Applications-(Part-1-2).aspx

my web.config:

```
    <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true" >
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="https://localhost/Connector" />
      </audienceUris>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <add type="Connector.Security.Azure.CustomJwtSecurityTokenHandler, Connector,   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
        <securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>
          <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
          <issuerTokenResolver type="Connector.Security.Azure.CustomJwtSecurityTokenHandler, Connector, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral">
            <securityKey symmetricKey="[mykey]" name="https://localhost/Connector" />
          </issuerTokenResolver>
        </securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>
      </securityTokenHandlers>

      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <trustedIssuers>
          <add thumbprint="[mythumbprint]"
        name="https://[mycompany].accesscontrol.windows.net/" />

        </trustedIssuers>

      </issuerNameRegistry>

    </identityConfiguration>

  </system.identityModel>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://[mycompany].accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wsfederation" realm="https://localhost/Connector" requireHttps="false" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
```

I checked response in fiddler. I receive the JWT token. Somehow my site does not send it to the right handler. Anybody know why or how to debug this?
token-type:jwt&lt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft provides an out of the box handler for JWT tokens.  If that fits your needs (i.e. you don't have any special requirements that made you write the custom handler) then I would suggest using that one.  I use it with ACS and it works like a charm.  You can install it as a nuget ( see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205064(v=vs.110).aspx )

Comment: A sample on how to set it up in the web.config once installed would have been nice. Still looking how to do it.

Comment: The Microsoft jwt security handler doesn't work with the WIF configurattion.  If you want to make it work you need to inherit it yourself and do the plumbing.  That's the reason why you won't find a config file as a sample.  However, if you wan afford it, I would suggest the new owin configuration pipeline.  It's orders of magnitude simpler https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/02/20/using-claims-in-your-web-app-is-easier-with-the-new-owin-security-components/ http://blog.baslijten.com/configure-claims-based-web-applications-using-owin-wsfederation-middleware/ )